# Live completion status of AAS cube processing

Tags: azure, cube, data-processing, azure-analysis-services

How to track the live status of Azure Analysis Services cube processing like percentage of completion or estimated end time etc., Please help

Comment: I've scoured the web and cannot find a solution. Right now I'm investigating xevents, SQL Profiler and Azure Metrics as possible solutions.